# Will a background resource in XXXHDPI scale across all devices in a descending order?

Tags: android

Ascending order, meaning the resource is placed in the ldpi folder only, results in rendering issues. Descending order works meaning only one file in `XXXHDPI` is scaled across all devices, however will `ldpi` devices and dpi devices use the resource.

Devices tested are ~`161 dpi` (`HDPI`). For the sake of space conservation and since using `ldpi` on higher resolution devices results leads to **OOM** issues, will a background resource in `XXXHDPI` scale across all devices in a descending order?

Comment: It will scale down perfectly, but... it won't for **all** devices. I.e.: tablets have different resolutions at different densities other than the standard ones used for mobiles.

Comment: In the event of the introduction of a device which uses `XXXXHDPI`, (four xs) would resources have to be placed in the `XXXXHDPI` folder?

Comment: Whenever a new version of Android will support it, yes. In the **future**. Not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will a background resource in XXXHDPI scale across all devices in a descending order?

It is unclear exactly what you mean by this.

If you mean that you have `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/image.png`, and you do not have a version of `image.png` in any other density-specific resource set, and you do not have a version of `image.png` in a higher-priority resource set, then yes, all devices will use the `-xxxhdpi` version of the image, resampling it as needed.

However, I expect that your results will look like crap on lower-density devices.

You seem fixated on shipping only one density's worth of images, and then for a density at one end of the spectrum. Instead, ship a few densities, to minimize how much scaling is required at runtime.

Comment: The background image is 1116 × 1722 for `XXXHDPI`. Is there a ratio on scaling across all densities?

Comment: @Skyfall: Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources): "To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities." More details and an example are in the docs.

Comment: So for example, `XXHDPI` would be (1116x1722) * (12/16) and so on reducing the numerator according to the ratio of each density?

Comment: @Skyfall: Yes, noting that `-tvdpi` is not included in that algorithm.

Comment: use vector images instead, they will take less space in APK and can be scaled for any density